# Implementing the library function `div` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement my own version of the library function `div` in Haskell. Here's my solution to the problem but it is not working the way I hoped and I'm not sure how else I can implement it. Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
div' :: Int -> Int -> Int
div' m n 
  |  n == 0     = 0
  |  n > 0      = div' m (n-1) - m
```

Comment: How is it not working? What error message do you get?

Comment: `div 42 0 == 0` looks quite wrong! And the recursive case looks wrong as well.

Comment: no error message, just got an infinite loop

Comment: Your theory is that `4 / 2` is equal to `4 / (2 - 1) - 4` ? I am interested to know how people come to make mistakes in programming languages. Can you describe to me how it is you came to the conclusion that `div m n` is equal to `div m (n-1) - m` ?

Comment: I tried to do the opposite of the multiply function, no wonder it wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you supposed to handle the divide by 0 case? If so, then make a separate case for it.

The base case for the division algorithm should be when a < b. What should the algorithm spit out if say you have 4 / 7? 
The recursive case should handle when a >= b. This should get you started for defining the div function on Natural numbers.

Comment: If you can't figure out how this should work, post an updated version of your code and I will take a look and walk you through the algorithm in more detail.